# Parse Comma separated column into a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that has the following structure

```
> idx noc
```

`idx` is a unique report id, but `noc` has a comma separated list of values.

I need to separate it out into a view, but i can't seem to figure out how to select what i need
i created a function split, that parses out comma separated values

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Split]
(
   @psCSString VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS @otTemp TABLE(sID VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(10)

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString) > 0
 BEGIN
  SET @sTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString) - 1, -1),
                    LEN(@psCSString)))
  SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString), 0),
                               LEN(@psCSString)) + 1, LEN(@psCSString))
  INSERT INTO @otTemp VALUES (@sTemp)
 END

RETURN
END
```

but i don't understand how to get the values out.

an example of the database values is:

```
idx 1
noc a,b,c
idx 2
noc a,x
```

i want to be able to see this:

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 x
```

do i need loops? please help point me in the right direction.

Comment: So, you want to use your function when you query your table?

Comment: yes, i think i need to, unless there's another way to break down the resultset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.IDX, T2.sID
FROM T1
CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_Split(T1.NOC) AS T2
```

Where obviously "T1" is your table.

If you want to show the rows that don't have the NOC filled just use `OUTER` instead of `CROSS`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: YES! from first glace it looks great! i'll check the data and mark your answer, thank you again! this is so much simpler than i though. i tried loops and more loops and failed

Comment: is there a way to also show those that have an IDX, but don't have the NOC field filled out?